# Extending a MySQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is it possible in CodeIgniter or PHP to extend a MySQL statement. For example. If I have `$query1`. Can I add onto `$query1` in another `$this->db->query()` instance:

```
$query1 = this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE a = b");

$query1(or 2) = $this->db->query("AND b = c");
```

Comment: @SnowBlind: I think he tried the example he showed in the question...

Comment: @Rocket Well, did that work out then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your statement in a var and extend the string if need:

```
$strStatement = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE a = b";

if ( /* whatever */ )
{
    $strStatement .= " AND b = c";
}

$objResult = $this->db->query( $strStatement );
```

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby I don't know why you accepted this answer, because it doesn't leverage *any* of the advanced features in codeigniter. There are classes already written that help you to do *exactly* what you want to do in many fewer lines of code than this soultion. See my answer below, and **read the documentation...**

Comment: I don't like to mess with CodeIgniter's MySQL method's mainly because I cannot use the NOW() function. I don't use those or models when it comes to Ci

Answer (score 0):

[check out the documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html). This can be accomplished (as one example) with:

```
$this->db->where('a', 'b');
if($condition)
{
    $this->db->where('b', 'c');
}
$this->db->get('users'); //implicitly runs a "SELECT *"
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted care to comment on why? This is a perfectly valid (and more efficient) way to accomplish exactly what the OP wanted...

Comment: Why you think this is more efficient? Dont you think, you have more overhead by calling 3 object methods than calling just one? But you are right, downvoting this answer is `false`. (_wasnt me btw_)

Comment: It was me and I agree with @Raisch. The down vote is because the accepted answer is faster and only call an object once. You are calling three times an object. It good to avoid thing like that to gain generation time...

Comment: @DavidBélanger I upvoted the other answer because they're both right. If my answer was incorrect, then a downvote would be appropriate. I don't think  teaching micro-optimization to someone [relatively] new to PHP/CI is a good idea - Realistically there is no difference in runtime between the two answers, to an average PHP/CI developer's site... The major difference between the two answers is readability; Different devs could prefer different styles, so why would a [perfectly valid] different approach be downvoted? *Not* upvoting would be a better option, if anything.